# Aerating wort with an air pump. What's the proper gallon rating?

Tags: aeration

I'd like to aerate three gallons of wort using my aquarium pump and 2 micron stone. The pump is rated for 10 gallon tanks. Is this sufficient?

Comment: Its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I heard someone tried to use an aquarium pump and a 2 micron stone it was a failure: the pump wasn't powerful enough. With a proper pump 30 min is said to be enough. 
However, there was Beersmith podcast where some guys from Maltose Falcon club made a split batch with a few different aeration techniques, and aquarium pump rated below pure oxygen (obviously) and below shaking the fermenter vigorously for 1 minute (surprise!). Taken that pump+stone kit costs $60 here in Aus, I personally dropped the idea at all.

Comment: A 2 micron stone is standard usage with a pump. How strong a pump... is the question. A .5 micron stone which is used for faster force carbonation is less likely to work or so I hear.

Comment: Here is a link (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ey0RFWIpnj0 go to 20:47) to an Q&A by White Labs where they said that it was necessary to shake the carboy for 20-25 minutes to get the proper aeration. To be fair I heard everything from 5+ minutes to get 8ppm of oxygen from shaking. What is interesting is that she said it doesn't matter too much for the first generation of yeast, but it is subsequent generations that will be unhealthy.

Comment: @fthinker There was a lab-quality study done by a micro using 250ml reference worts in Ehlrenmeyer flasks and various methods of aeration, measuring with a dissolved oxygen meter. Surprisingly, they were able to get to 8-10 ppm of O2 by 45 seconds of vigorous shaking. The caveat is that it is a lot easier to shake 250ml than 19L. I use a tennis ball in the punt of PET carboys, and if I time my rocking correctly, I can get a prodigious amount of air into solution -- you can see it come out of solution as extremely fine bubbles (sort of like the foam that rises in a Guinness).